# React Capital case in routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm working on a very simple react app, but when I try to use router in always makes pathname with first letter Capital case and I don't have any idea why.

**app.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Layout from "./pages/Layout"
import Basket from "./pages/Basket"
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from "react-router"

const app = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
        <IndexRoute component={ItemsList}></IndexRoute>
        <Route path="basket" name="basket" component={Basket}></Route>
    </Route>
    </Router>,
app);
```

**Header.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router"

export default class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { location } = this.props;
        const basketClass = location.pathname.match(/^\/basket/) ? "active" : "";
    return (
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                         <li class={inventoryListClass}><Link to="/">Inventory</Link></li>
                        <li class={basketClass}><Link to="basket">Basket</Link></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    );
    }
}
```

does anyone now why it uses capital letter "**/Basket**" when I explicitly specified "**basket**" in route parameter.

thanks.

**Layout.js**

```
import React from "react";

import Footer from "./Footer";
import Header from "./Header";

export default class Layout extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const { location } = this.props
        return (
            <div>
                <Header location={location} />
                <div class="container">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible you have capitalized `/Basket` path in your url

Comment: Also it isn't clear, why you are trying to get `this.props.location` property from non route handler `Header` component. It shouldn't have `location` prop. Could you provide component code, which renders `Header`?

Comment: ok just added layout.js components which renders header component

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I found the problem. I put capital capital "B" in `<link to=Basket`this line in my header.js

`<li class={basketClass}><Link to="Basket">Basket</Link></li>`

So it was just a type. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to check for active routes, by the way, there is `activeClassName="active"` which does the same.